# Packaging and distributing a python (for windows) application for client side

Tags: python

Lets say I have developed a desktop application using python for windows users. I want to distribute this application.

So what is the standard process of packaging and distributing? I want the setup to be installed other .msi or .exe setups are installed.

Answer (score 1):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

> PyInstaller is a program that converts (packages) Python programs into
>   stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris and
>   AIX. Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works
>   with any version of Python since 2.3, it builds smaller executables
>   thanks to transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use
>   the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full
>   compatibility.

[cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

> cx_Freeze is a set of scripts and modules for freezing Python scripts
>   into executables, in much the same way that py2exe and py2app do.
>   Unlike these two tools, cx_Freeze is cross platform and should work on
>   any platform that Python itself works on. It supports Python 2.3 or
>   higher (including Python 3), since it makes use of the zip import
>   facility which was introduced in 2.3.

Once you have it packaged into a self-contained environment, be it either a single exe or a directory structure, you can use any standard Windows Installer application if you need special installation procedures. Or you can simply distribute it as the .exe, ready to run.